# Dojo : Failed to load resource

Tags: checkbox, dojo

I'm trying to follow this **[dojo tutorial]**[1](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/checkboxes/index.html) , a very simple , but it doesn't run
work.
**here is the Html code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>

  <script>
    dojoConfig = {
      parseOnLoad: true,
      baseUrl: "http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/",
      isDebug: true
    };
  </script>
  <script src="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

  </div>
  <script>
    require(["dijit/form/CheckBox"], function(CheckBoxk) {
      var chbox = new CheckBoxk({
        id: "chbox1",
        checked: true
      });

      chbox.placeAt("container", "first");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**and this is Google chrome output**: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are hosting your own custom version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript on your system (i.e. because you are using localhost), you should instead use ESRI's CDN to load the API resources.

Ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">
```

`<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>`

Otherwise it appears you simply have a bad web server configuration on your system, i.e. "arcgis_js_api" doesn't point where you think it points. Check your web server log for more information about the 404.